# jquery .html() working only with alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I have a javascript function, using jQuery, which manipulates a `<div id="message">` to print error and status messages.

It looks like this:

```
function messageShow(msg, type) {
    $('#message').addClass("message red");
    $('#message').html(msg);
    $("#message").slideDown(200, 0).fadeTo(200, 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#message").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, 0);
    }, 5000);
    //alert('asdasd');
}
```

The content of the div is only seen if I uncomment the `alert();` line.
There is no redirect after this, so the page is not changed before the content is loaded.

I tried:

```
$('#message').html(msg, function() { ... });
```

Just to be sure, but that doesn't work either.

The div:

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

The css:

```
.message {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.red {
    background: #daa;
    color: #855;
}
```

Comment: Need to see some of your html here, and relevant css definitions for .message, .red, and #message.

Comment: Your code could be made more optimal by utilizing jQuery's [method chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp).

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ea8xrokn/. Have you checked the console for errors elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Yeah. Ok here. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/au72c93b/

Comment: You have a race condition. setTimeout is an asynchronous operation.

Comment: No errors shown in the console. In jsfiddle.net it works >.<

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ea8xrokn/2/

Comment: It behaves the same  way.

Comment: Sorry. I found the issue. I was using a .load() function on the div containing the message div, and it got erased. So there was no message div to begin with. Thanks for the help. Sorry for missing that.

Answer (score 0):

I do recomend you to use jquery **delay** function instead.

Try this:

```
function messageShow(msg, type) {
 $('#message').addClass("message red");
 $('#message').html(msg); 
 $("#message").slideDown(200, 0).fadeTo(200, 1).delay( 500 ).fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, 0);
}
```